# Como fazer com que a checkbox fique 'checada' após salvar no banco?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, checkbox

As minhas `checkbox` estão salvando normalmente, porém, quando eu saio da página e volto, elas não permanecem checadas.

[image: View]

**Clientes.blade.php**

```
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="/user/update/client">

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$user->ID}}" />

        <h1>BEM VINDO ADMINISTRADOR!</h1>

        <div><input type="button" value="Início" id="inicio" name="Início" onclick="window.location.href='/inicioadm';"></div> <br>        
         @foreach ($clients as $client)                                    
        <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th width="30%"><p>Nome: {{$client->Nome}} <input name="clientes[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$client->ID}}"> </p></th>       
        </tr>
        </table>

        @endforeach

        <br><div><input type="submit" value="Salvar" id="salvar" name="Salvar" onclick="window.location.href='/desenvolvedores"/div>


    </form>
</body>
```

**Controller**

```
public function updateClient()
    {                    
        $clientList = Input::get("clientes");
        $user = Input::get("id");

        \App\Relation::where('ID_user', $user)->delete();

        if($clientList)
        {
            foreach($clientList as $c)
            {
                $r = new \App\Relation();
                $r->ID_clients = $c;
                $r->ID_user = $user;

                $r->save();
            }
        }

        return redirect("/desenvolvedores");
    }
```

**Model Clients**

```
class Clients extends Model
{
    public function Users ()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("\App\Relation", "relations", "ID_clients", "ID"); //conectando as tabelas 'users' e 'clients' do banco de dados
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `checked` no seu checkbox

Answer (score 2):

Num projeto que eu utilizei o Laravel 5, eu também tive um cenário parecido.

Eu tinha um relacionamento belongsToMany e precisava marcar no checkbox quais itens existiam no relacionamento.

Eu utilizei o método `Collection::contains`. Ele vai verificar na coleção, sem precisar fazer várias consultas no banco, mas apenas trabalhando com o resultado já carregado.

Veja um exemplo:

```
@foreach ($grupos as $grupo)

<div class='checkbox'>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" 
              name="grupo_id[]" 
              value="{{ $grupo->id }}" 
             {{ $usuario->grupos->contains($grupo->id) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
        {!! $grupo->nome !!}
    </label>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Observe que no meu exemplo, `Usuario`tem relacionamento `BelongsToMany` com `Grupo`.

Eu listei todos os itens de `Grupo` e através do relacionamento já carregado de `Usuario` eu checo através do método `contains` para saber se aquele id está presente no relacionamento carregado. Se estiver, o checkbox ficará marcado como `checked`.

Comment: Não conhecia o contains, boa! +1

Comment: @JuniorNunes o legal do Contains é que a verificação é feita internamente pelo PHP. Salva em muitas ocasiões.